# Is there a way to use USB 3.1 charger to charge 2.0-based devices?

Tags: usb-2, usb-3.1-type-c, usb-pd

I have a USB 3.1 charger supporting power delivery and quick charge technologies. Since it has a 3.1 socket, are there any adapters that would let me use that socket to plug in a regular micro-usb device and charge it?

Comment: USB 3.1 is backward compatiable with USB 2.0.  You won't charge a USB 2.0 device faster with a USB 3.1 cable but they are compatiable.

Comment: @ Ramhound is correct.  All you need is the proper cable for the device.

Comment: They do make adapters for usb-c if that is what you mean.....https://www.amazon.com/Syntech-Adapter-Thunderbolt-Compatible-MacBook/dp/B077FD3VG4/ref=pd_day0_hl_147_5/133-5339500-3010038?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B077FD3VG4&pd_rd_r=2a3b31e7-3449-11e9-9e0d-076cbdff4877&pd_rd_w=DNEGB&pd_rd_wg=QYAnF&pf_rd_p=ad07871c-e646-4161-82c7-5ed0d4c85b07&pf_rd_r=3NZSVBNHTGBZ8SR7BXFR&psc=1&refRID=3NZSVBNHTGBZ8SR7BXFR